# Can't install XBMCBuntu properly

Tags: gui, amd, xbmc

I tried several Times to install multiple Versions of XBMCbuntu but it's always booting into Terminal without GUI. When I try to start XBMC I get a long list of Graphics errors. I'm installing it on the HP Probook 4530s without monitor(its crashed) I connected an Acer(1600x900) Monitor. I think the cause of the problems is because there is an Intel GPU and an AMD GPU installed.

How can I get the GUI to start?

Comment: Maybe let people see what the graphics errors are instead of leaving them to attempt to determine them telepathically?

Comment: Yea, sorry i thought about that too but the first problem is, i'm atm not at home and second problem is how do i get the Log when i've only the terminal? And its a lot of text.

Comment: Okey, found out that it would be possible with SSH. I will post it tonight.

Comment: I decided to install Windows with XBMC on Top, that way the problem is solved but not really nice. But i think the problem was in general cause of AMD + Ubuntu